# Compile .java file without knowing public class name

Tags: java

I'd like to know how to compile .java files without knowing the public class name.

To provide an example use case: I am operating a sandbox, and users are allowed to send me a string. I write that string to a .java file, which I compile, evaluate the resulting class and reply the output.

**?????.java**

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

If I were to randomly assign `?????.java` a name such as **test.java** and ran the command `javac test.java` then it would fail

*error: class HelloWorld is public, should be declared in a file named HelloWorld.java* like so:

**HelloWorld.java**

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Should I forego the ability to compile Java, or is there an alternative solution?

Comment: Er, get the users to tell you? In the file name? You don't actually need the class name, only the filename.

Comment: Now that I read your question text again, I'm confused. If *"users [...] send [you] a .java file"*, then you already know the name of the file, so why renamed it. And since the file is supposed to contain a `public` class, it's up to the user to ensure it does. Knowing the name of the file means you also know the name of the class, so you know how to both compile and run it.

Comment: @Andreas to clarify, they are only sending a string of text, not a named file.

Comment: So instruct them to call the class something specific, e.g. `Challenge`, `Assignment`, `Exercise`, etc. If you name the file `Challenge.java` and it won't compile, or if it compiles but doesn't create a class of the right name, or the class doesn't have a `main()` method, then they failed the challenge/assignment/exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Well... To be able to evaluate custom code you also have to know a class name with `main` method.

I think the cheapest way is to force users to stick to some sort of code convention i.e *"package name should be foo.bar.baz, class name is Qux, main class is mandatory"*. In that case you can just pass through an error message from compiler to user *as is* and show a code convention.

Less quick way is to do some dirty tricks like wrapping received code properly with another class with known name, messing with package names and then try to make reflective call to inner classes `main` method, but in that case you'll have a problems with proper error reports and easy to do it wrong.

The proper and potentially long way is to take java source code parser *(like [this](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/wiki/Manual))*, build AST, find out top-level class, rename file according package/class name and execute javac (or even produce bytecode from AST).

**EDIT**

Also you can take a took at [java-repl](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/wiki/Manual) project. This can allow you to eval script-like programs.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can actually compile the class if you do not declare it as public.

example:

```
class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Hello world");
   }
}
```

Save the file as .java, and compile as such on the cmd

```
javac .java
```

You can run afterwards by using the class name

```
java Test
```

Comment: It's about compiling the file, not running it, sure. But this answer targets directly that... since OP asked how to Compile the file w/o knowing the name of the class.

Comment: Question says *"which I compile, **evaluate the resulting class** and reply the output"*. Evaluate means run, and for that you need class name.

Comment: @Andreas ... not necessarily.  If you know the name of an interface that it implements ....

Comment: @StephenC The question specifically shows a class with a `main()` method, which means that you need to run it. Even if you were right, you'd still need to know the name of the class in order to instantiate it, before being able to use the interface to invoke a method.

Comment: Again no.  You can use reflection to load a class and invoke its `main` method WITHOUT knowing its name.  And you do not need to instantiate a class to invoke its `main` entry point method because it is a `static` method.

Comment: So I wonder, would it be a valid solution to actually run a command based on the returned error? example, use the return value from the javac .java --> error ---> grep -o -P '(?<=class).*(?={)' which should be the name of the class, store it in a variable and then run it as java "storedClassName".

Comment: @StephenC How can you load a class without knowing it's name? `Class.forName()` requires a name. The second point of my previous comment was that if you were going the interface route (which your prior comment was about), you'd still need to know the name of the class to instantiate it. Either way, you need to know the class name to either 1) call the static `main()` method, or 2) instantiate the class so you can call interface methods. To "evaluate" a class you just compiled, you need to set up a classloader to find the class, then load it by name.

Comment: *"How can you load a class without knowing it's name?"* - Easy.  Use `javap` and scrape the output ... or write your own code to extract the name from the ".class" file.  Probably other ways too.

Answer (score 0):

> If I were to randomly assign ?????.java a name such as test.java and ran the command javac test.java then it would fail
>
> error: class HelloWorld is public, should be declared in a file named HelloWorld.java

OK, so look at the error message!  The compiler is helpfully telling you what the name of the file should be.  Don't throw that information away.  Parse the error message to find the correct file name, re-name the file, and try again.

Comment: OP already saw that error message. It's in the question text.

Comment: @Andreas, OK, I missed seeing that in the OP's message, but my point is still the same.  The OP has the text of a Java file, and doesn't know what it's name should be.  If he makes up a name, and tries to compile it, the compiler helpfully _tells him_ what the name should be.  Obvious solution then, is to extract the file name from the error message and try again.

Comment: I actually find this really clever, thanks @jameslarge

Comment: Just look out so that you don't loop infinitely on files containing more than one public class. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion. When somebody send you xxxx.jar file, you must save it to somewhere, so you know the folder path. Then you could use below code to get name. After you get the file name and path, use java reflection technology to get the methods and invoke the methods.

```
final static void showAllFiles(File dir) throws Exception
{
   File[] fs = dir.listFiles();
   for(int i=0; i<fs.length; i++)
   {
      // here you can get file name and path, then use reflection to get the instance and methods.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to compile a ".java" file if the basename of the source file does not match the class name *in* the source code.  If you don't know what the filename should be, then your only option is to (partially) parse the source code to find it.

---

But to be honest, this is problem that you should be addressing in a different way:

- If you generated the source code yourself, then you *should* know when the class name is, and therefore you *should* be able to deduce the correct name for the ".java" file.
- If you are compiling a file that was "provided for you", then you could (and IMO should) insist that it is provided in a ".java" file with an appropriate filename.  If the filename doesn't match the classname, that is a mistake ... and you don't know whether the mistake is the filename or the classname!

---

Here's a thought experiment for you.  Suppose someone provided you with source code files:

- A.java ... contains class `A`.
- B.java ... also contains class `A`.

What should you do with that?  If you tried to figure out the "correct" filename from class name in the file, you could miss that the user made a mistake in B.java and put the wrong class name into the source code!

In short, you have two pieces of contradictory information.  Either of them could be incorrect.  If you let one automatically take precedence over the other, you miss mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

By now you might have already implemented it.
But this is for those trying to implement such system now after 2018,
Java 11 supports directly running the java files.

If you have xxxx.java file, you can directly execute it with

```
java xxxx.java
```

This works with different filename and classname.
Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE) for the `java` command.

Answer (score -3):

The name of the class to keep the same name compiled，In "public class HelloWorld ",'HelloWorld' is the class name,At the same time,it is name of 
compiled.

```
public class Hello{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

That you can compiled as such on the cmd `javac Hello.java`.
Run `java Hello`

---

```
public class Hello2{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println("Hello, Man");
    }
}
```

You can complied as such on the cmd `javac Hello2.java`

Run `java Hello2`